# Getting a value from a selected cell's row

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like a macro what does the following: opens a new file (template) and fills its cells with values from the selected cell's rows. So far, I created this:

```
Sub CreateReport()
'
' 
'

'
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "D:\_munka_\E6645\Egyéni Office-sablonok\megf_nyil_sablon.xltx", Editable:= _
        True
    Range("E11:I11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[makroproba.xlsm]Munka1!R4C6"
    Range("E11:I11").Select
End Sub
```

How can I pull data from the selected cell's column "G" for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always specify a workbook and worksheet for ranges! Otherwise it is not clear for VBA where exactly you expect this range to be.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateReport()
    Dim OpenedWb As Workbook  'set the workbook to a variable so we can reference it
    Set OpenedWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:= _
        "D:\_munka_\E6645\Egyéni Office-sablonok\megf_nyil_sablon.xltx", Editable:=True)

    'referece which workbook and worksheet you mean
    OpenedWb.Worksheets(1).Range("E11:I11").FormulaR1C1 = "=[makroproba.xlsm]Munka1!R4C6"
    
    ' pull value from another workbook's cell
    OpenedWb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value =  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("yoursheetname").Range("G1").Value
End Sub
```

Note that `Worksheets(1)` is the first workbook in the tab bar! You can also reference a workbook by its tab name using `Worksheets("Sheet1")`.

[Avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

// edit according comment

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateReport()
    'first remember what was selected as `Selection` quickly changes when you open other workbooks!
    Dim SelectedData As Range
    Set SelectedData = Selection

    Dim OpenedWb As Workbook  'set the workbook to a variable so we can reference it
    Set OpenedWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:= _
        "D:\_munka_\E6645\Egyéni Office-sablonok\megf_nyil_sablon.xltx", Editable:=True)

    'referece which workbook and worksheet you mean
    OpenedWb.Worksheets(1).Range("E11:I11").FormulaR1C1 = "=[makroproba.xlsm]Munka1!" & electedData.EntireRow.Cells(1, "F").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
End Sub
```

Comment: What I'd like to achieve: I select a row by selecting one of its cell. Pressing macro button (report) opens a new template and - for example - gets the same row's data from column "F" and puts it into the opened template's specific cell.

So, 
OpenedWb.Worksheets(1).Range("E11:I11").FormulaR1C1 = "=[makroproba.xlsm]Munka1!R4C6" should look like OpenedWb.Worksheets(1).Range("E11:I11").FormulaR1C1 = "=[makroproba.xlsm]Munka1![selectedrow's "F" column data]"

Comment: @DarkArchon That would be a bit different. See my edit.

Comment: Can I ask for a little modification? In this way, the whole cell gets copied, including value, cellformat and everything. I only need its value, the rest of them not needed. Thanks!

Comment: @DarkArchon What you describe cannot be correct, the formula can only pull a value but no format!

Comment: To be more precise, it seems it deletes the original cell's category as general. Selection.NumberFormat = "General" must be applied after inserting values for some reason.

Comment: @DarkArchon this is because Excel "thinks". You can see the same happening when you manually enter a date into a cell. It automatically switches from general to date. You will probably have to deal with that as Microsoft thinks this is a feature not a bug.

Comment: @PEH I'd like to make the filename and sheet name to be general, so if I rename the file or change the first sheet's name won't affect the script.

`code`
OpenedWb.Worksheets(1).Range("D2:E2").FormulaR1C1 = "=[" & mainFilename & "]" & mainSheet & "!" & SelectedData.EntireRow.Cells(1, "G").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

Of course, I have defined mainFilename and mainSheet as strings. It does work, but is there a nicer solution?

Comment: @DarkArchon no, everything good with that solution, looks nice to me.

Comment: @PEH How can I do this for every selected row? Now it works only for one. It would be awesome if I select more cells, and the macro generated every file. Thanks!